# Patternlab twig includes with params

Tags: twig, patternlab.io

I am using the node version of [patternlab](http://patternlab.io) with twig as template engine. I am using twig because my codebase is written in twig - so using mustache it not an option.

I simple try to include an pattern:

```
<button type="button" class="btn {{ buttonClass }}">{{ cta }}</button>
```

in an other pattern with:

```
{% include "base-button" with {'buttonClass': 'btn-primary btn-xs'} %}
```

This does not work. The pattern is included but the variable `buttonClass` is not set.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Would not it miss the extension of your include like base-button **.html** ou base-button **.html.twig** ?

Comment: An extension is not needed here. Patternlab has its own logic to find pattern by name; see: http://patternlab.io/docs/pattern-including.html. My Pattern gets included - so the path is resolved - but the vars are not there.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the twig integration in this repo https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternengine-node-twig.

There are other issues with twig core features described here: https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/issues/554

I finally decided to switch to the php/twig edition and the same twig-patterns are working as expected. If anybody have to use the node edition, i recommend to use mustache.

Comment: Maintainer of Pattern Lab Node here.You're spot on in that the Twig engine of PL Node is rough around the edges. This issue attempts to address that too: https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/issues/285  I want to respond though, to your comment that one should use mustache with PL Node. We have a very mature Underscore and Handlebars engine too, with React and Liquid in the works.   Good luck with your PL journey!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are plans to pass the Twig rendering in Pattern Lab Node to PHP, however, this isn't ready yet, but using [The Twig engine for Patternlab/Node](https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternengine-node-twig) you can pass a variable via an include. It doesn't work exactly the same as normal twig but it does work.

```html
{% set buttonClass = 'btn-primary btn-xs' %}
{% include "components-button" with buttonClass %}
```

You can also pass multiple variables:

```html
{% include "components-button" with buttonClass anotherVariable %}
```